# How to Create a new instance of class under an AppDomain

Tags: c#, reflection, dll, appdomain

I am trying to invoke a class to run under a separate AppDomain but I am getting an exception about noting being able to load the class or one of its dependencies. Here is an example of what I am doing.

```
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");
IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity("NewUser");
IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
ad.SetThreadPrincipal(principal);
TestClass remoteWorker = (TestClass)ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
                         binFolder+"\\TestProject.dll",
                         "TestClass");
remoteWorker.Run(data1,data2);
```

In my separate TestProject I have one class named TestClass:

```
 public class TestClass : MarshalByRefObject
 {
      public void Run(string name, string path)
      {
           //Some stuff
      }
  }
```

I've checked all the paths for everything and they are correct. I am getting the error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'K:\\Installer\\Bin\\TestProject.dll' 
or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)
```

I've tried changing paths, moving it to the currently executing assembly. Still nothing. The DLL is located in K:\Installer\Bin\TestProject.dll. I am running this under admin so it has permissions to the Dll.

Comment: Did you try catching the `ReflectionTypeLoadException` exception? Maybe "TestProject.dll" has some dependencies that the runtime couldn't resolve.

Comment: The only thing in includes are system Dlls. How would those not be resolving?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Changed my code to this:

```
AppDomainSetup domainSetup = new AppDomainSetup 
                             {PrivateBinPath = binFolder+"\\TestProject.dll"};
AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain",null, domainSetup);

TestClass remoteWorker = (TestClass)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
                          binFolder+"\\TestProject.dll",
                          typeof(TestClass ).FullName);
```